# Accessing the first column of first row of a table in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

```
               <tr ng-repeat="a in people">
                    <td>
                        {{a.firstname}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{a.lastname}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{a.email}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

protractor code

```
   var firstname = element.all(by.repeater('a in people'));          
   expect(firstname.get(0).getText()).toEqual('george');
```

This returns the entire first row. How do I get the first column? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get it like this:

```
 var all = element.all(by.repeater('a in people')).all(by.css('td'));          
 expect(all.get(0).getText()).toEqual('george');
```

`element.all(by.repeater('a in people'));` it will find just one element. If on the page will be two elements with this **repeater** text it will find two. But you need make search by `td` also.

Answer (score 1):

Technically when ng-repeat executes, it will repeat the element into the dom, In your case < tr ng-repeat='a in people'> tag will be repeated. So element.all(by.repeater('a in people')) results in multiple rows, hence get(0) method will return first row.

We can use following code to get first column of the first row.

```js
      var firstname = element(by.repeater('a in people').row(0).column('a.firstname')); 
      expect(firstname.getText()).toEqual('xyz');
```